# Expansion of variadic type parameters of outer struct within member struct's template-template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates

If you have a template struct  then you can use T as the type of a *value* parameter of a member template:

```
template <typename T>
struct SMoo
    {
        template <T I, typename T2>
        struct SBaa {};
    };

SMoo<int>::SBaa<3, bool> moobaa;
```

You can do the same with a *variadic* outer template:

```
template <typename ... VT>
struct SMoo
    {
        template <VT ... VI, typename T2>
        struct SBaa {};
    };

SMoo<int, bool>::SBaa<3, true, bool> moobaa;
```

You can also use T as the type of a value parameter of a *template-template parameter* of a member template:

```
template <typename T>
struct SMoo
    {
        template <template <T I, typename T2> typename TT>
        struct SBaa {};
    };

template <int I, typename T>
struct SCaw {};

SMoo<int>::SBaa<SCaw> moobaacaw;
```

You can combine these to get:

```
template <typename ... VT>
struct SMoo
    {
        template <template <VT ... VI, typename T2> typename TT>
        struct SBaa {};
    };

template <int I, typename T>
struct SCaw {};

SMoo<int>::SBaa<SCaw> moobaacaw;
```

But this seems to fail as soon as there's more than one VT parameter:

```
template <typename ... VT>
struct SMoo
    {
        template <template <VT ... VI, typename T2> typename TT>
        struct SBaa {};
    };

template <int I, typename VT>
struct SCaw {};

template <int I, bool B, typename VT>
struct SMew {};

SMoo<int>::SBaa<SCaw> moobaacaw;

//SMoo<int, bool>::SBaa<SMew> moobaamew; // <<=== FAILS HERE (WHY?)
SMoo<int, bool>::SBaa<SCaw> moobaacaw2; // <<=== ALSO, DOESN'T FAIL HERE (WHY?)
```

the error is:

```
<FILE>:5:27: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class ... VT> template<template<template<VT ...VI, class T2> class TT> template<class ... VT> template<VT ...VI, class T2> class TT> struct SMoo<VT>::SBaa’
   15 | SMoo<int, bool>::SBaa<SMew> moobaamew; // <<=== FAILS HERE (WHY?)
      |                           ^
<FILE>:15:27: note:   expected a template of type ‘template<class ... VT> template<VT ...VI, class T2> class TT’, got ‘template<int I, bool B, class VT> struct SMew’
```

It's like the VT parameter isn't being matched accurately.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: GCC is just plain wrong, and clang fails in all cases. I suspect it has to do with the compiler not knowing how to match the pack expansion against non-pack NTTPs. It can be fixed for individual cases, but I'm not sure you'll be able to get it matching in the way it appears you want to use this. And good luck getting GCC and Clang to agree on any approach with this sort of template programming.

Comment: Best advice I have is to use `std::integral_constant` instead of NTTPs in template parameter position. I even tried to create `SCaw` and `SMew` using a pack expansion and [it still didn't match correctly in either compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/cGMYxfx6e)

Comment: N4928: §13.4.4/3: "When P’s template-head contains a template parameter pack (13.7.4), the template parameter pack will match zero or more template parameters or template parameter packs in the template-head of A with the __same type and form__ as the template parameter pack in P (__ignoring__ whether those template parameters are template parameter packs)." [emphasis mine]. This shouldn't make the code bad, right? (because the mismatched parameters don't have same type and form) - but it's still a weird rule.

Comment: Just to clarify, I never claimed this was not well-formed (besides the case you expected to fail), I think this is just a compiler bug, but at least in my experience with template metaprogramming, declaring a template-template parameter in a dependent context with a mixture of type and non-type template parameters is a very unusual thing to do.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The case that failed I did _not_ expect to fail. Do you believe that line is not well formed if uncommented?

Comment: This is intended to be used for building a template to be used in overloading, so that I can constrain an the type of an overloaded function parameter to being derived from a given _template_ base class. The problem is dealing with base classes of all the different possible template parameter formats. I'm currently trying to create a single class to handle all template base classes of the form <T1 v1, T2 v2, ..., TN vN, typename T (or typename ... VT)>. I don't believe it's possible to create a complete set (although that'd be some nice functionality to add to C++2C or whatever).

Comment: at the risk of sounding redundant, the case I was referring to which you expected to fail was the one which you expected to fail. The last line, currently uncommented in the question. Also regarding future functionality to address these cases, check out https://wg21.link/P1985